# "growing" animation effect for a timeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flash

I am creating a timeline and it has circles on the line indicating different events. When the user hovers on the circle, I want a line to "grow" out of the circle with text of the event on the end. Does anyone have any suggestions on what to use to make this effect possible. Javascript? CSS? Flash?

Comment: It would be easier if we could see what you have so far. Please add the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS3 to create the animation. 
Here's the full code : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cgKGf